# SC_THREAD dynamically sensitive to port toggle?

Tags: systemc

Is there an elegant way to wait on a port trigger (toggle) rather than an event inside a SC_THREAD? In other words, I want a thread in Module B to be dynamically triggered based on a toggle on a port from Module A. My current method is to generate an event from the port toggle, and then use the event inside whichever threads needs to be triggered. But is there a better way?

Update: answer from jclin is just perfect.

Comment: Please include relevant code in your question. Without it, it's not clear, for example, what type your port has (some port types have events inside them that you can use). In addition, what does "dynamically triggered" mean? Do you want to use static or dynamic sensitivity, or do you not care?

Comment: Did you try and wait for a signal or input port's `value_changed_event()`?